# Examples of problems in $\mathsf{IP}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, interactive-proofs

What are some examples problems with a direct proof that they are in $\mathsf{IP}$, other than Graph Non-Isomphism?

I have been looking for a while, but no luck so far.

Comment: Well, IP=PSPACE, so you might consider some PSPACE-complete problems, such as TQBF, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula

Comment: I'm looking for a direct proof,  @Aryeh but thank you.

Comment: The proof of IP = PSPACE *is* a direct construction of an interactive protocol for TQBF. Chapter 8 of Arora - Barak has protocols for GNI, quadratic nonresiduosity, #SAT, TQBF, and the permanent.